# R Find Distance Between Two values By Group

Tags: r, data.table

```
HAVE = data.frame(INSTRUCTOR = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),
STUDENT = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1),
SCORE = c(10, 1, 0, 0, 7, 3, 5, 2, 2, 4, 10, 2),
TIME = c(1,1,2,3,2,1,1,2,3,1,1,2))
 
WANT = data.frame(INSTRUCTOR = c(1, 2, 3), 
SCORE.DIF = c(-9, NA, 6))
```

For each INSTRUCTOR, I wish to find the SCORE of the first and second STUDENT, and subtract their scores. The STUDENT code varies so I wish not to use '==1' vs '==2'

I try:

```
HAVE[, .SD[1:2], by = 'INSTRUCTOR']
```

but do not know how to subtract vertically and obtain 'WANT' data frame from 'HAVE'

Comment: @akrun do you have suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(data.table)
setDT(HAVE)
unique(HAVE, by = c("INSTRUCTOR", "STUDENT")
  )[, .(SCORE.DIF = diff(SCORE[1:2])), by = INSTRUCTOR]
#    INSTRUCTOR SCORE.DIF
#         <num>     <num>
# 1:          1        -9
# 2:          2        NA
# 3:          3         6
```

To use your new `TIME` variable, we can do

```r
HAVE[, .SD[which.min(TIME),], by = .(INSTRUCTOR, STUDENT)
  ][, .(SCORE.DIF = diff(SCORE[1:2])), by = INSTRUCTOR]
#    INSTRUCTOR SCORE.DIF
#         <num>     <num>
# 1:          1        -9
# 2:          2        NA
# 3:          3         6
```

One might be tempted to replace `SCORE[1:2]` with `head(SCORE,2)`, but that won't work: `head(SCORE,2)` will return length-1 if the input is length-2, as it is with instructor 2 (who only has one student albeit multiple times). When you run `diff` on length-1 (e.g., `diff(1)`), it returns a 0-length vector, which in the above `data.table` code reduces to zero rows for instructor 2. *However*, when there is only one student, `SCORE[1:2]` resolves to `c(SCORE[1], NA)`, for which the diff is length-1 (as needed) and `NA` (as needed).

Comment: i add new column TIME to differentiate

Comment: ... and how do you intend to use `TIME`?

Comment: to make sure that we are taking the first and second score for each student for each instructor

Comment: i think it is resolved by HAVE[order(INSTRUCTOR,STUDENT,TIME)]

Comment: it work beautiful! I am wondering from a practice point of view, how would you do this on dplyr?

Comment: i try: WANT  = HAVE %>% group_by(INSTRUCTOR) %>% mutate(SCORE.DIF = diff(SCORE[1:2])) but how to specify unique student in this case?